# activemq-artemis log monitoring and alerting

Tags: activemq-artemis

I have been looking to find if there is an alternate way to monitor  warning/errors that are in logs. Currently I am using the logs to know the error code which keeps on changing for every update. Is there an alternate way to know them?

Comment: What do you mean that the error code "keeps on changing for every update?" Which error code are you referring to? What updates are you making? Please clarify.

Comment: the log message format keeps on changing to write e regular expression and read the logs.I am trying to find a way other than logs can we get the same info through other system exposed parameters.

Comment: In what way does the log message format keep on changing? Can you give a concrete example?

Answer (score 1):

Apache ActiveMQ Artemis uses the JBoss Logging framework to do its logging and is configurable via the logging.properties, see the [documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/logging.html).

You could use a [custom handler](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/logging.html#use-custom-handlers) to intercept warning/errors.